# issues with proguard and 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' library

Tags: android, gson, android-proguard

I have found the proguard issues and answer related to com.google.gson library but not with which are related with com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' library

I am using `'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'` library. without proguard its working fine but when i enable proguard the below code gives the wrong result.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
            UserDetails userDetails = gson.fromJson(response, UserDetails.class);
            if (userDetails != null) {
                Logger.appendInfoLog("gsonData" + userDetails, "gsonData");
                Logger.appendInfoLog("gsonData" + userDetails.getCity(), "cityName");
            }
```

In this code userDetails.getCity() is returning null.

What i have tried is :- To keep this library from obfuscation in proguard-rules.pro I have declared it like this

```
-keep class com.google.code.gson.**
```

But its not working, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Gson uses member field names (via reflection) by default to do the parsing so if you use tools like ProGuard your class `UserDetails` will have it's members field names changed. The thing you have to do is to keep proguard from obfuscating your model classes.

ex: if your model classes are in mypackage.model package you can add rule:

> -keep class mypackage.model.** { *; }
>
> -keepclassmembers class mypackage.model.** { *; }

Comment: instead of keep class mypackage.model.** { *; } i used -keepclassmembers  public class com.leadsquared.app.models.**{
      <fields>;
    } and it works fine please put this statement also in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have *@SerializedName()* annotation for every field in UserDetails? Proguard obfuscates all names (class/field/method names), so gson will not find fields in your class.